# Does the partition id of the Kafka Topic to which message was sent maches with partition id of open method in ForeachWriter?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a requirement where I need to create a file specific to each partition. I saw the partition to which messages are getting posted doesn't corresponds to exact file in hdfs. How does partitions are getting assigned in consumer?

Producer:

```
def send(key: String, value: String): Unit = {
    val recordMetadataFuture = kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, key, value))
    try {
      val recordMetadata = recordMetadataFuture.get
      println("Topic " + recordMetadata.topic + " Offset " + recordMetadata.offset + "Partition " + recordMetadata.partition + " timeStamp" + recordMetadata.timestamp)
    } catch {
      case ex: Exception => {
        ex.printStackTrace
      }
    }
  }
```

Consumer :

```
streamedEvents.writeStream.foreach(new ForeachWriter[Message] {
    var fSDataOutputStream: FSDataOutputStream = _
    var partition: Long = _
    def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
      println("Partition id ::" + partitionId + " version :: " + version)
      val configuration = new Configuration();
      val hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("URI"), configuration);
      val path = new Path("Path" + partitionId + ".txt");
      val fs = path.getFileSystem(configuration)
      if (fs.exists(path)) {
        fSDataOutputStream = fs.append(path)
      } else {
        fSDataOutputStream = fs.create(path)
      }
      partition = partitionId
      true
    }

    def process(e: Message) = {
      val message = e.message
      val messageKey = e.messageKey
      val partition = e.partition
      val offset = e.offset
      val eventData = e.getMessage();

      var eventMessage = getObjectMapper.readValue(eventData, classOf[EventMessage])

      fSDataOutputStream.write(getObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(eventMessage.getBytes)
    }

    def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
      fSDataOutputStream.close()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How does partitions are getting assigned in consumer?

In Kafka you have full control on how to produce to and how to consume the messages from topic partitions.

For a producer the partitioning strategy is based on the message key. By default it calculates `hash(key) % number_of_partitions` and distributes the messages across partitions. If a key is not specified, messages are sent to partitions on a round-robin basis. In addition, you can also write and provide your custom [partitioner](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Partitioner.html) class.

For a consumer you can configure `partition.assignment.strategy` in the [Consumer Configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs). This defaults to class `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor`